# Internal Server Error while loading Google Heatmap when the data point is more than 1700

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I am working on a POC where the datatable output has large number of latitude,longitude and volume(weight). I am facing an issue when the number of point(or record in datatable) is more than 1700.Though it works fine if the number of data point is less than 1700.

We have more than 1M data point which has to be plotted on map..Can any one suggest what could be wrong? The error I get for larger data point is below

**Error Message : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Also please find the code below.

**Code Behind**

```
   [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]
    public static string CreateDatatable()
    {

        MapDataDataContext mz = new MapDataDataContext();
        var zipData = from zp in mz.GeoMapDatas
                      select zp;
        var geoQuery = (from e in mz.GMapTables
                    join d in mz.GeoMapDatas on e.ZIP equals  d.ZIPCode
                    select new { e.Measure, d.Latitude, d.Longitude }).Take(2000);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Measure", typeof(long));
        dt.Columns.Add("Latitude", typeof(float));
        dt.Columns.Add("Longitude", typeof(float));

        geoQuery.CopyToDataTable(dt,LoadOption.PreserveChanges);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        json = json.TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');
        return json;
    }
```

**Java script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table'] });
    function OnLoad() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/CreateDatatable",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: initialize
        });
    }

    var map, pointarray, heatmap;

    function initialize(response) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(response.d);
        var heatData = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            // heatData.push( new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].Latitude, obj[i].Longitude));
            heatData.push({ location: new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].Latitude, obj[i].Longitude), weight: obj[i].Measure });
        }
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000,-100.0000),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

    var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatData);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });

        heatmap.setMap(map);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Guys It was related to the JSON string lenght limitation. I fixed it but setting the limit high for maxjsonlenght in web.config `<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration> `